# Programmatically set values for input ports in SIMULINK

Tags: input, port, simulation, modeling, simulink

I have simple system model in SIMULINK which I am trying to black-box test with minimum effort. I know that using MATLAB script, I can automate simulation and testing processes.

I have multiple `In1` (SIMULINK block for top-level-input) ports and I want assign values to those input ports. I know that using `Signal Builder` block I can assign step/pulse/sine_wave/constant signals very easily, but that defeats the purpose of scripting and automating tests.

Does anyone know if it is possible to assign input values programmatically to the `In1` ports in SIMULINK? If yes, how?

I will be trying to find the answer myself meanwhile. If I have any luck before, I will simply answer it! :)

Comment: This question becomes relevant if the model will be later be used as a part of a larger system.

Answer (score 4):

I would actually recommend importing data directly to the root-level ports of the models, rather than using the From Workspace block, that's precisely what they're designed for. See [Import Data to Root-Level Input Ports](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/importing-data-to-root-level-input-ports.html) in the documentation for more details.

Comment: This is the correct approach.  You do not need or want to use From Workspace blocks (as other answers have suggested) as that approach a) forces you to physically change your model (i.e. changing the Inport to a From Worspace) b) potentially prevents you from using this model as a sub-component of another model (i.e. using this model in a Model and block) and c) potentially prevents you from generating code for the model allowing it to be used a component in other real-time code.

Answer (score 2):

The In-Block is for models that are meant to form a new block/ subsystem.

If you want to determine your input signals in a script, then you need to use the "From Workspace" block!

[FromWorkspace block in operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyD4P.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Because I also need to use RTW (now Embedded Coder), I was wondering how the code generation will be effected if I choose to use `From Workspace`. Do you think I will still get the functions and input parameters generated properly for my C code with "From Workspace" input blocks?